# Can't get Jitsi-meet installed in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: error-handling

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04, no separate server.
I thought that I didn't have to install Jitsi-meet (on my Windows 8.1 it runs just like that), but when I open it on Linux it shows the starting screen --> I give permission to Cam/Mic --> the screen turns black.

--I tried to install JM in command mode with https://codepre.com/nl/como-instalar-jitsi-meet-en-ubuntu-20-04-lts.html and get the following error message:

```
E: jitsi-meet-prosody: subproces van pakket jitsi-meet-prosody werd script post-installation geïnstalleerd gaf de foutwaarde 1 terug
E: jitsi-meet-tokens: vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
E: jitsi-meet-turnserver: vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
E: jitsi-meet: vereistenproblemen - blijft ongeconfigureerd
```

--Installing with Synaptic Package Manager gives the same result.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "Error 1" simply means "Something went wrong with some subprocess." Unfortunately, that's not enough to offer useful advice. Edit your question to include the complete apt output.

Comment: @ Pilot6  Thanks for your reaction, but I don't come any further now,  Do I have to go through the whole installation anyway if Jitsi works from the taskbar, e.g. as in Windows 8.1?  I get the impression that https://codepre.com/nl/como-instalar-jitsi-meet-en-ubuntu-20-04-lts.html is a typical _server_ installation, or is it a generic install?  Regards, Fré

Comment: Avoid asking unrelated questions in comments. We generally won't answer those. If the question is important and related, edit your original question above.